# How does flutter size and position UI elements (widgets)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How does flutter size and position UI elements (widgets)? Is it determined by parent widget or by child widget itself? I want to know, what is the algorithm being used under the hood, when it processes the widget tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great article on the topic: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

TL;DR. Widget gets size constraints from the parent. Widget chooses its size (within the constraints) and reports back to parent. Parent positions the widget.